# Is there a way to pass an onclick function through the MUI Datagrid into a column for renderCell?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

I am working on a react app and I am using the MUI Datagrid to display some data. I have used a rendercell to add an edit icon which I would like to open a pop up modal.
Below is the column.

```
export const someColumn = [
  {
    field: "price",
    headerName: "Price",
    flex: 1,
    cellClassName: "name-column--cell",
  },
  {
    field: "editPrice",
    headerName: "Edit Price",
    flex: 1,
    editable: false,
    renderCell: (params) => {
      return (
        <FiEdit onClick={() => alert(params.row.price)} /> //I want to open modal with the ID as a parameter} className='cursor-pointer' />
      );
    },
  },
];
```

In the component that has the Datagrid, I have the openModal function that should open the modal.

```
const openModal = () => {
  setShowModal(true);
}
```

This is my Datagrid

```
<DataGrid
  autoHeight
  rows={someArray}
  columns={someColumn}
  slots={{ toolbar: CustomToolbar }}
/>;
```

How can I get the button to open up the modal? Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-definition/#using-hooks-inside-a-renderer):

> The renderCell property is a function that returns a React node, not a
> React component.
>
> If you want to use React hooks inside your renderer, you should wrap
> them inside a component.

So you can create a custom component that renders both the button and the modal, and use it in the `renderCell` prop of the column.

For example:

```
// Create a custom component that renders the button and the modal
const OpenModalButton = ({ row }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={handleOpen}>{row.col2}</Button>
      <BasicModal
        open={open}
        onOpen={handleOpen}
        onClose={handleClose}
        row={row}
      />
    </>
  );
};

const columns = [
  { field: "id", hide: true },
  { field: "col1", headerName: "Column 1", width: 150 },
  {
    field: "col2",
    headerName: "Column 2",
    width: 150,
    renderCell: OpenModalButton // Use the custom component here
  }
];
```

You can see the whole example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-cloud-wxn3px?file=/App.js).